# From database validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorcery

How is it possible to show the errors from the model validations if the user for instance types in an already used username or email. The validations I am using do work, and the page renders nicely if a validation stops it from being created. However how can i show the errors to the user. Where on the page doesn't matter. I know I can use :message => "The Username/Email is already in use". But how do I make this be more specific, how can I make the errors come directly from the validation checks.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery! 

  attr_accessible :username, :password, :email

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :password
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :password
  validates_confirmation_of :password

end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to save or create the record validation errors are saved.

You can use `@user.errors` to get the validation errors and display them. You can see some details in the [Rails Guide for validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors).

These will use the default messages, which you can improve by changing `config/locales/en.yml`

Some example code:

```
<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <div class="error"><%= msg %></div>
<% end %>
```

If you want to customize the validation message for email, for instance, open `config/locales/en.yml` and add the following under `en:`

```
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              taken: "has already been taken"
```

Comment: Can I simply add this to the view, or do I have to supplement the create action in the UsersController with something like this: @user.errors

Comment: You can just add this to the view. It will render nothing if the user has no errors (which it won't if it is new, or you just visited the edit page) and will render a div with a message for each error message if you tried to save the user and validation failed.

Comment: You can also use `<%= f.error_messages %>` if you are using a form, as well as `<%= f.error_messages_for :attribute %>`

Comment: Ridiculous error: NoMethodError in Sessions#new
What do I do, any tips?

Comment: Can you give the entire error message? That isn't enough information to help.

Comment: COMPLETE ERROR: ----

NoMethodError in Sessions#new

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <h1>Log in</h1>
2: 
3: <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
4: <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
5:   <div class="error"><%= msg %></div>
6: <% end %>
7:     <div>

Comment: So that means that @user is the wrong variable. Replace it with whatever you assign the user to in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

[validates_uniqueness_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)

```
Validates whether the value of the specified attributes are unique across the system. 
Useful for making sure that only one user can be named “davidhh”.
```

It can also validate whether the value of the specified attributes are unique based on a 
scope parameter:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, :scope => :account_id
end
```

**EDIT**

I misread the question. Daniel's answer is right. [Examples](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors)

Comment: I've already been there, and I did notice something new now, btw that all of them had somehow their own :message, therefore I can use those multiple time. However again I can't pass :message, :message, :message after another multiple times, how would you intend to to this? Also what is a scope parameter, and what does that really mean?

Comment: oh I misread the question .. Daniel's answer is what you are looking for